# Thin Server Architecture, OAuth2.0 Protected Pages

Tags: javascript, security, oauth, web

I've been reading about Thin Server Architecture lately -- http://www.thinserverarchitecture.com/ (does it go by another name?) -- and I have a question about password protecting pages with OAuth2.0.

Suppose I have a page /secure.html that I only want users to access once they've been granted an OAuth2 bearer token.   The token would be generated via some /login REST call.

How do thin server architecture pages "secure" pages?  If the user goes to /secure.html and the request header does not have "Authorization: Bearer " what does the validation of the token and the redirect.  Is this something on the web server side?  If so, I'm not seeing OAuth2 support for Apache, Lighttpd, Nginx, etc.  Or... does the Javascript on secure.html read the token (from the Authorization Header or I guess a secure cookie), call some /verify REST function, and redirect to a login page if necessary?

Thanks